# How to split a string of yearly responses into columns for each year in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, transpose, explode

I have the following table `answer` with the columns `id`, `value`, where value is a string with yearly information separated by comma:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0,2,3 |
| 3 | 1,3,0 |

In the case above, for `id` 1 the values represent 3 for 2021, 2 for 2020 and 0 for 2019. The latest year is always in the end.

How can I transform the result above into this table below?

| id | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 2019 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021 | 3 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2 |
| 3 | 2019 | 0 |

I tried several examples similar to split() and explode() from other languages.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: version 5.7.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1